# ActiveAdmin Timeout count on heroku

Tags: heroku, pagination, timeout, activeadmin

Im getting a lot of H12 Timeouts on heroko just on the user index page after filter, this is my activeadmin page:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register User do

  menu :parent => 'Users'

  actions :all, :except => [:destroy, :new]


  filter :first_name, :as => :string
  filter :last_name, :as => :string
  filter :email, :as => :string, filters: [:starts_with]
  filter :kind, as: :select, collection: User::KINDS
  filter :gender, as: :select, collection: User::GENDERS

  permit_params :first_name, :last_name, :email, :status, :kind,
                :raw_password, :referrer_code

  index pagination_total: false  do
    column(:id){|u| link_to u.id, [:admin, u]}
    column :first_name
    column :last_name
    column :email
    column :kind
    column :gender
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      f.input :first_name
      f.input :last_name
      f.input :email, as: :email
      f.input :raw_password, label: "New Password", hint: "Leave it blank to keep the current password"
      f.input :status, as: :select, collection: User::STATUSES
      f.input :kind, as: :select, collection: User::KINDS
      f.input :gender, as: :select, collection: User::GENDERS
      f.input :birthday, as: :date_picker
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

I can see on the logs a multiple counts ex:

```
Started GET "/admin/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bfirst_name_contains%5D=&q%5Blast_name_contains%5D=&q%5Bemail_starts_with%5D=rdude244%40hotmail.com&q%5Bkind_eq%5D=&q%5Bgender_eq%5D=&commit=Filter&order=id_desc" for ::1 at 2017-11-01 10:03:05 -0400
Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"first_name_contains"=>"", "last_name_contains"=>"", "email_starts_with"=>"rdude244@hotmail.com", "kind_eq"=>"", "gender_eq"=>""}, "commit"=>"Filter", "order"=>"id_desc"}
  AdminUser Load (110.8ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (1085.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
   (1105.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%') LIMIT 1 OFFSET 30) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  User Load (1531.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%')  ORDER BY "users"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  Rendered /Users/hugorincon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@moviepass-admin/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (4034.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4484ms (Views: 223.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4046.2ms)
```

There is a way to remove that SELECT COUNT(count_column)? to reduce the load time.

Comment: Using 'contains' pattern on big data it's insane. If you search email use 'equals' pattern on needed column. Of course a column should be indexed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the limit 1/offset 30 query is from [PaginatedCollection#build_pagination](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/95b8276d307aa86b7fbe27f870adfa24e5dbd378/lib/active_admin/views/components/paginated_collection.rb#L105). My guess is the other queries are from this module also, so I'm not optimistic you can disable them without monkey patching. I do see these queries are 7-8 times faster now an index is used but 1500ms for an index range scan on a 750K table is still slow. Maybe there are other database issues? To find the other queries I would place some breakpoints in this module and step through to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks I just sent a comment with more info.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove that request but still getting Timeouts on heroku every time.

[heroku status metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jftCY.png)

```
Nov 02 16:21:36 moviepass-admin heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/admin/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bemail_starts_with%5D=Schatzinator1%40gmail.com&commit=Filter" host=cs.moviepass.com request_id=8735fd5a-4d62-462a-9f0d-9a558413c720 fwd="65.196.51.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http 
Nov 02 16:21:48 moviepass-admin heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/admin/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bemail_starts_with%5D=gnarlynoodlez.email%40gmail.com&commit=Filter" host=cs.moviepass.com request_id=57c82b9d-c70a-4f63-88aa-e48695571e36 fwd="99.42.145.134" dyno=web.4 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http 
Nov 02 16:22:01 moviepass-admin heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/admin/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bemail_starts_with%5D=Schatzinator1%40gmail.com&commit=Filter" host=cs.moviepass.com request_id=bbc5716f-af22-4b3f-93e0-2694ff62da88 fwd="200.84.242.248" dyno=web.2 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http 
Nov 02 16:22:02 moviepass-admin heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/admin/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bemail_starts_with%5D=pandey.nivedita02%40gmail.com&commit=Filter" host=cs.moviepass.com request_id=729400a2-18d9-4204-931f-c8302d4a6442 fwd="184.75.152.175" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

Every timeout just have this requests:

```
Started GET "/admin/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bfirst_name_contains%5D=&q%5Blast_name_contains%5D=&q%5Bemail_starts_with%5D=rdude244%40hotmail.com&q%5Bkind_eq%5D=&q%5Bgender_eq%5D=&commit=Filter&order=id_desc" for ::1 at 2017-11-01 10:03:05 -0400
Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"first_name_contains"=>"", "last_name_contains"=>"", "email_starts_with"=>"rdude244@hotmail.com", "kind_eq"=>"", "gender_eq"=>""}, "commit"=>"Filter", "order"=>"id_desc"}
  AdminUser Load (110.8ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (1085.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  User Load (1531.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE 'rdude244@hotmail.com%')  ORDER BY "users"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  Rendered /Users/hugorincon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@moviepass-admin/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (4034.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3484ms (Views: 223.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3046.2ms)
```

Im currently using puma and 4 standard-x2 dynos, puma config:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 4)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 2)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Comment: Your request completed in 3484ms but Heroku timed out after 30000ms? I don't know what is going on here. Maybe the Heroku Scout add-on will help or maybe Heroku support?